# Slightly Jagged Border Line with CSS

Tags: css, background, border

Can this kind of background border edge by drawn using CSS?  I see lots of examples for 45% jagged edges, but nothing this drawn out with these smaller angles.  I suspect it can be done, but haven't been able to figure it out.

[image]

If it can be done, I'd appreciate a little help getting started.

EDIT: Here is some code and a jsfiddle that I have started playing with.  Have the general shape, but the problem is the gaps between the border lines.

HTML

```
<div id="angle-border" class="clearfix">
    <div class="left-border"></div>
    <div class="left-center-border"></div>
    <div class="right-center-border"></div>
    <div class="right-border"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */
}
#angle-border {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.left-border {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    padding-right: 2px;
}
.left-center-border {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
    padding-left: 2px;
}
.right-center-border {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    transform: rotate(7deg);
}
.right-border {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BitBug/zodh07oc/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of. As an alternative, perhaps you could make the background that the jagged edge is part of into a CSS "background-image". You could create said background image in a vector drawing program like Adobe Illustrator or Sketch, then include it in your CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Yes I can do this as background image, but I have to use this look throughout the site with various colors and other variations and the overhead of all the images will start to add up, so my first preference is if it can be done with CSS.  But, as you say, may not be possible.

Comment: not sure about the feasibility of this, but could you use an SVG and dynamically colour it using css?

Comment: Yeah I think hairmot is right, the "dynamic" part of that would have to come from SASS, though. (Well, technically you could use JavaScript to dynamically change the styling, too). I don't know a lot about SVG but it's clear that you can add classes and IDs for styling purposes and reference them in your CSS: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-7.

Comment: In terms of generating the "base" SVG, again, you could use Illustrator or Sketch and export to SVG. I'm thinking that you could probably just play around with the generated SVG code and CSS styles and figure out which SVG paths you need to reference in your dynamic modifications.